# cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

**ERROR MESSAGE:  #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint**

hello i can't create table foreign key... how to do this... i have two table..
the first table got two primary key then the 2nd table is 1 primary key...
the first table is
`courseid varchar(5)`
and `courseyear int`
and the second is `subj_id varchar(5)`

```
create table studentload(
student_id varchar(11) not null,
courseid varchar(5) not null,
courseyear int not null,
subj_id varchar(5) not null,
foreign key (courseid,courseyear) references course(courseid,courseyear),
foreign key (subj_id) references subject(subj_id)
)
```

**EDIT**

this is all table that I inserted already

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
  `courseid` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `courseyear` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `coursedesc` varchar(50),
  `subj_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`courseid`,`courseyear`)
) 


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subject` (
  `subj_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `subj_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `courseid` varchar(5),
  `courseyear` int(11),
  foreign key (`courseid`,`courseyear`) references `courseid` (`courseid`,`courseyear`)
)
```

Comment: How do you know you can't create the foreign keys?

Comment: it gave me error `Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: What happens when you try to add the constraint?  How exactly are you trying to add the constraint?  What happens when you do?  Do you get an error message?  What is the error message?  Please edit your question to update it with this information, cut & pasted from the screen, not paraphrased, so that we can help you.

Comment: And that's it, nothing more to that error message? Also, do you think that information might have been relevant to your question?

Comment: I edit it... here it is

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: view my answer posted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650302/cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/18650510#18650510 and fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e850e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is sample [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e850e)

You have mandatory to add `primary key (subj_id)` in your `studentload` table

In your foriegn relationship courseid is not tablename. It should be

```
"references course(courseid,courseyear)"
```

Like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
  `courseid` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `courseyear` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `coursedesc` varchar(50),
  `subj_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`courseid`,`courseyear`)
); 


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subject` (
  `subj_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `subj_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `courseid` varchar(5),
  `courseyear` int(11),
  foreign key (`courseid`,`courseyear`) references `course` (`courseid`,`courseyear`),
  primary key (`subj_id`)
);

create table studentload(
  student_id varchar(11) not null,
  courseid varchar(5) not null,
  courseyear int not null,
  subj_id varchar(5) not null,
  foreign key (courseid,courseyear) references course(courseid,courseyear),
  foreign key (subj_id) references subject(subj_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used "references `courseid`(`courseid`,`courseyear`) ". courseid is not your tablename. It should be "references `course`(`courseid`,`courseyear`) "

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it is due to the order of the table creations. Make sure you create the non-foreign key tables first.