# Can not create foreign keys in MySql

Tags: mysql

It want to create 2 tables. 1 table has created but another one is giving error in creating! Note: Both table are Innodb

```
journal:
---------
jr_date --> primary
entry_no --> primary
description
```

DDL:

```
 CREATE TABLE `journal` (
  `jr_date` date NOT NULL,
  `entry_no` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`jr_date`,`entry_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now want to create following table but getting error! Why?

```
ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint   
SQL Statement:

CREATE TABLE `accounting`.`journal_details` (    
  `jr_date` DATE NULL,    
  `entry_no` SMALLINT NULL,    
  `serial` TINYINT NULL,    
  INDEX `fk_journal_details_jr_date_idx` (`jr_date` ASC),    
  INDEX `fk_journal_details_entry_no_idx` (`entry_no` ASC),    
  CONSTRAINT `fk_journal_details_jr_date`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jr_date`)    
    REFERENCES `accounting`.`journal` (`jr_date`)    
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,    
  CONSTRAINT `fk_journal_details_entry_no`    
    FOREIGN KEY (`entry_no`)    
    REFERENCES `accounting`.`journal` (`entry_no`)    
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I could not understand why foreign keys are not created?

Comment: Is the Engine InnoDB ?

Comment: You will need to post both table DDL, but typically this error is because the types differ in the tables, or because the FK isn't actually a key in the other table. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/16969060/314291

Comment: data types of journal table columns?

Comment: check the type of the entry_no  column in journal table . It must be smallInt to be used as foreign key to journal_details table.Also to use the **DELETE CASCADE** entry_No should be primary key in Journal table

Comment: Please get the updated text. Table are innodb, columns datatypes are okay.. but where is the problem?

Comment: you can create table from designer if script is not working

Comment: MySQL likes hiding the actual error message. You have to run `show enginne innodb status` and browse the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a composite primary key:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`jr_date`,`entry_no`)
```

It doesn't make any sense to link to those columns separately because they aren't necessarily unique.

I'm pretty sure you only want *one* foreign key.

```
  CONSTRAINT `fk_journal_details`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jr_date`, `entry_no`)    
    REFERENCES `accounting`.`journal` (`jr_date`, `entry_no`)    
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `jr_date`,`entry_no` is a composite primary key on table `journal`. To reference it in `journal_details`, you will similarly need to reference it as a composite key, not as 2 single simple foreign keys.

i.e. Change the foreign key like so:

```
  CONSTRAINT `fk_journal_details_jr_date_entry_no`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jr_date`, `entry_no`)    
    REFERENCES `accounting`.`journal` (`jr_date`, `entry_no`)    
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ec74/1)

Comment: Quite possibly. If so, OP probably also wants to declare `journal_details(jr_date, entry_no)` as primary key.

Comment: In general, I would try and avoid composite keys and tend to favour a new, narrow, surrogate. Doing this also avoids common join issues across composite keys.

Answer (score 0):

You lack an index on `journals.entry_no`.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> *[for each foreign key in the referencing table]*, there must be *[in the referenced table]* an index where **the referenced columns are listed as the *first* columns** in the same order.

The `PRIMARY KEY` on `journals(jr_date, entry_no)` covers for the reference to `journal.jr_date`, but not for the reference to `journals.entry_no`;

Answer (score 0):

Here the primary key is composite key ((`jr_date`,`entry_no`))

Primary key is in combination and you try to give reference of a single column which is not a primary key..