# Why can not I give a foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql

Why can not I give a foreign key constraint?

ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `arena`.`like_history` (

  `p_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,

  `u_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,

  `ldate` DATETIME NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`, `u_id`),

  INDEX `u_id_idx` (`u_id` ASC),

  CONSTRAINT `p_id`

    FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`)

    REFERENCES `arena`.`picture` (`p_id`)

    ON DELETE CASCADE

    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

  CONSTRAINT `u_id`

    FOREIGN KEY (`u_id`)

    REFERENCES `arena`.`user` (`ul_id`)

    ON DELETE CASCADE

    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: Do the tables `picture` and `user` definitely exist in `arena`? Are their primary keys the `p_id` and `ul_id` respectively (not `u_id` for the second one???)

Comment: 1 - show the table structure of `arena`.`picture` and `arena`.`user`; 2 - what are database engines for all these 3 tables?

Comment: Are those referenced table already created?

Comment: @Mihai: Unless which, it would have not a `1215`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the referenced table columns are defined.
But for them to be eligible for referring from other tables, they *MUST* have *`INDEXed`*

As per documentation on `foreign key` constraints:

> REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)

Define an `INDEX` on both `picture.p_id` and `user.ul_id` columns.

And other primary constraints are that,

- The child column definition MUST match with that of parent column.
- Database `ENGINE` type must be same.

**Refer to**:

- [**MySQL Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>       [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
>       REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
>       [ON DELETE reference_option]
>       [ON UPDATE reference_option]
>
> reference_option:
>       RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION