# Failed to add the foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I try to add a foreign key on a table but whenever I try I always have this error

> ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'total_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'all_votes'

The table that is being created is this one (members is another table that has nothing to do with the error, so give no importance to it)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS all_votes ( 
id_vote INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_member INT,
name_member VARCHAR(20),
vote VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
type_of_vote VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
topic VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (id_member) REFERENCES members(id)
);
```

And this is the table that occur the error

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS total ( 
topic VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, 
type_of_vote VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
counts INT NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY (topic) REFERENCES all_votes(topic)
);
```

I've read a ton of answers, but none of them seems to work for me. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30056091/9351336) was the most instructive that summarize more less every other one.

I guess the error has to do with the reference of a foreign key to a non-primary key. The thing is that a lot of people says it's possible, but I didn't find a single code example, so I probably messed up somewhere there.

Answer (score 0):

'MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys'https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html  mysql will generate keys for you in the referencing table but YOU have to define them in the referenced table. in other words you need to add a key on topic in all_votes.

This syntaxes

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS all_votes ( 
id_vote INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_member INT,
name_member VARCHAR(20),
vote VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
type_of_vote VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
topic VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL #,
#FOREIGN KEY (id_member) REFERENCES members(id)
);

alter table all_votes
    add key abk1(topic); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS total ( 
topic VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, 
type_of_vote VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
counts INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (topic) REFERENCES all_votes(topic)
    );
```

Note: I have commented out  #FOREIGN KEY (id_member) REFERENCES members(id)

Comment: I changed a little bit the all_votes. Now primary keys are id_member AND topic, while id_vote is totally deleted. Even like this, the error is still there. Did I understand something wrong? Does it have to be the only primary key?

Comment: No but topic has to be the first node of the key.

Answer (score 0):

because `all_votes.topic` column should be defined as `PRIMARY OR UNIQUE KEY` to be able to define a referenced foreign key for `total.topic` column.