# Cannot add foreign key constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

**MySQL:**

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS otes_db;

USE otes_db;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS school(
    school_code CHAR(3),
    school_desc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    school_head INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY(school_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(school_head) REFERENCES user(user_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
    user_id INT UNSIGNED,   
    user_lname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_fname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_mname VARCHAR(255),
    user_email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    user_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_type ENUM('CEO', 'VP', 'HEAD', 'CHAIR', 'STUD') NOT NULL,
    user_isActivated ENUM('Y', 'N') DEFAULT 'N',
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);
```

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint), I have checked for the following:

- InnoDB Engine is set in `school` table
- The referenced key is a primary key (`user_id`)
- The data types are the same (`INT UNSIGNED`)

However, I'm still getting the error with the `school_head` and `user_id`. Anything I missed?

Comment: You need to create the table `user` *before* you create the table `school`. Plus `user` is a reserved keyword, you need to quote it (better find a different name, that is not a reserved word)

Comment: If you could make this an answer, I will upvote and accept it. Thanks also for the tip about `user` (that's why it always highlights as blue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the user table first