# MySQL Error code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key contraint. I cannot see the error

Tags: mysql

I've got the famous 1215 Error but I can not find the reason why...

I've already seen several topics as [MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint?rq=1) , and I followed all their tips, but I don't see the error....

(Squemas are automatically generated by MySQL Workbench...)

With the following structures, for the table "modalidad", I got:

```
Error code 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Code:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qvh056`.`centro` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qvh056`.`centro` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo',
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `orden` INT NULL,
  `activo` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qvh056`.`compania` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qvh056`.`compania` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `codigo` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Codigo contable. Se puede identificar a la compañia con empresa y codigo.',
  `nombre` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `alias` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `centro_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '\"empresa\"',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_compania_centro1_idx` (`centro_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_compania_centro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`centro_id`)
    REFERENCES `qvh056`.`centro` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qvh056`.`modalidad` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qvh056`.`modalidad` (
  `id` CHAR(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo + centro\n',
  `codigo` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `centro_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `modality` CHAR(2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_modalidad_centro1_idx` (`centro_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_modalidad_centro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`centro_id`)
    REFERENCES `qvh056`.`centro` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Did you insert the centro table rows first?

Comment: In SQLfiddle it works fine.

Comment: @MiniFridge It's just the creation. No rows by now.

Comment: @mzurita in MySQL works fine too. I've pasted your code in the mysql console after creating qvh056 database. You should try it. I have not very good experiences with MySQL workbench.

Comment: I solve this… Only drop all tables (erase the squema) and rebuild entire database and the problem misteriously solved… (I had the same problem executing script in phpmyadmin)