# #1452-Cannot add or update a child row:a foreign key constraint fails (`testdatabase`.`#sql-1

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

How add foreign key in existing table

```
ALTER TABLE retailer_commission ADD FOREIGN KEY (Retailer_Id) REFERENCES retailer(Id)
```

[image]

Comment: show both tables (parent/client) schema...it seems both columns schema/data type/properties are not same....

Comment: Both tables schema are same(datatype is int(11))

Comment: may you show output of "show create table mytable" for both tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 0):

Since the types of the `Retailer_id` column in the `retailer_commission` table and the `Id` column in the `retailer` table are both the same type (`int(11)`), there must be another explanation for your error.

One likely explanation is that the `retailer_commission` table has records with `Retailer_id` values which refer to records in `retailer` which do not exist.

If the following query gives you a non empty set, the records returned should be considered as problematical:

```
SELECT rc.*
FROM retailer_commission rc LEFT JOIN retailer r
    ON rc.Retailer_id = r.Id
WHERE r.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: I am using this query,Query working fine result has been display.New error has display "#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdatabase`.`#sql-15c0_dc`, CONSTRAINT "

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved,In foreign key table there is lot of records that is the reason to occurred this error,I have truncate this table(Foreign table) then execute "ALTER TABLE retailer_commission ADD FOREIGN KEY (Retailer_Id) REFERENCES retailer(Id)",Query has been successfully done.

Comment: My answer is likely the reason for what was happening.