# what I need to do for this mysql error (#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint) when I have category table with name column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table products
( 
  Product_ID varchar(30) not null,
  Product_Name varchar(30) not null,
  Price float not null,
  name varchar(30),
  Description varchar(200) not null,
  Brand varchar(30),
  Image varchar(30),
  Primary key(Product_ID),
  Foreign key(name) REFERENCES category(name)
);
```

Comment: You may want to add some more details on your actual problem, for example how `name` is declared in `category`.

Comment: Create backup of category and product table data then truncate both table data...Now apply foreign key and then fill correct data which one should be related with references.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)