# golang -> gorm: How I can use sql.NullInt64 to be int(10) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, go, foreign-keys, go-gorm

```
type Contact struct {
  gorm.Model
  PersonID sql.NullInt64
}

type Person struct {
  gorm.Model
}
```

I am trying to use [gorm](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/) with mysql in the previuos code but I have the following problem:

I want:

- Use `sql.NullInt64` to work easily with null values.
- Use the base model definition `gorm.Model`, including fields `ID`, `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt`, `DeletedAt`.
- Add a constraint `Db.Model(&models.Contact{}).AddForeignKey`.

My problem:

- `Person.ID` become `"int(10)"` in mysql.
- `Contact.PersonID` become `"bigint(20)"`
- MySql need the same type for [pk and fk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/16969176#16969176).

Some body can help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The "magic" on `gorm.Model` is only the name of the fields, any `struct` with these fields look like this according to the gorm documentation, at the end of [Conventions](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/models.html#conventions)

For example: Save records having `UpdatedAt` field will set it to current time.

Or

Delete records having `DeletedAt` field, it won't be deleted from database, but only set field `DeletedAt`'s value to current time, and the record is not findable when querying, refer [Soft Delete](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#delete)

So solve the issue is very easy, this is the code for my case:

```
package models

import "time"

type Model struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primary_key;type:bigint(20) not null auto_increment"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time `sql:"index"`
}
```

So, now I only need use it as base model :)