# MySQL foreign key constraint error code 1215

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Can anyone see the problem with my create statement for table contactgroup. I keep getting error code 1215 can't create foreign key constraint.

```
create table contact( 
ContactID int(5) not null auto_increment, 
ContactName varchar(255) Not null, 
ContactNumber int(5), 
ContactEmail varchar(255), 
primary key(ContactID))ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

```
create table contactgroup(
ContactGroupID int(5) Not Null,
ContactID int(5) Not Null,
primary key(ContactGroupID),
key fk_contactgroup_ContactID (ContactID),
constraint fk_contactgroup_ContactID 
foreign key(ContactID) 
references contact) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: This is a faq, google your title & read the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention both the table *and* the primary key column of that table when defining a foreign key constraint:

```
FOREIGN KEY (ContactID) REFERENCES contact(ContactID)
```

Comment: Why do you answer this instead of close voting as an obvious duplicate &  downvoting as obvioulsy without research effort?