# Workbench Forward Engineer Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship, forward-engineer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2mnv.png)

I want to forward engineer my er diagram to physical database.I have this error, I tried different ways to solve it but still no luck. Can someone Please help me.
Here is the error message:

> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign
>   key constraint

SQL Code:

---

```
-- Table `mydb`.`Guest`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Guest` (
  `Location` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `User_KexinM_Email` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_KexinM_Email`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Guest_User_KexinM1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`User_KexinM_Email`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`User_KexinM` (`Email`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed
>
> Fetching back view definitions in final form. Nothing to fetch

Comment: You probably have a foreign key `fk_Guest_User_KexinM1` already from some earlier attempts. Try to rename it to e.g. `fk_Guest_User_KexinM2` or something. You may want to add the script code for `User_KexinM`, although the workbench will very likely do it correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)