# Creating a foreign key in SQLAlchemy fails

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want every user to have a value called `allocatedstorage` and `availablestorage`. Those two values are stored in another table. However when I create the following database it shows the error below. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    role= db.Column(db.String(20));
    usersessiontoken = db.Column(db.String(500), unique=True)
    hasstorage = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('storageinformation.allocatedstorage'))
    hasavailablestorage = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('storageinformation.availablestorage'))

    storageinformation = db.relationship('StorageInformation', backref='user')

class StorageInformation(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'storageinformation'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    allocatedstorage = db.Column(db.Integer)
    availablestorage = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint') [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE user (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \n\tusername VARCHAR(15), \n\temail VARCHAR(50), \n\tpassword VARCHAR(80), \n\t`role` VARCHAR(20), \n\tusersessiontoken VARCHAR(500), \n\thasstorage INTEGER, \n\thasavailablestorage INTEGER, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tUNIQUE (username), \n\tUNIQUE (email), \n\tUNIQUE (usersessiontoken), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(hasstorage) REFERENCES storageinformation (allocatedstorage), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(hasavailablestorage) REFERENCES storageinformation (availablestorage)\n)\n\n']
```

Comment: You've 2 columns trying to reference a foreign **key** column, but neither referenced columns are keys. Did you mean to add a single foreign key column such as `storageinformation_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('storageinformation.id'))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 1):

- In my case, the actual **reason was not shown in the output of migration** command
- I was able found the problem only by **running the same command in database console**

**Command was**

`ALTER TABLE assignment ADD FOREIGN KEY(session_id) REFERENCES battery (session_id)`

**Actual problem**

`Create table 'db_name/#sql-5f9_11e' with foreign key constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns.
Cannot add foreign key constraint`

[Mysql Doc -> Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.
>
> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.