# Updating some/all value inside row to null when another row in same table is deleted MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table like below

```
id  tetangga1 tetangga2
1   null     null                       
2   1        3              
3   1        4           
4   4        5         
5   4        6         
6   6        null
```

i need to update either tetangga row's value to NULL when one of the row inside the same table is deleted, in example, if i delete the row 1, then the table would look like this

```
id  tetangga1 tetangga2                       
2   NULL        3              
3   NULL        4           
4   4           5         
5   4           6         
6   6           NULL
```

explanation: row 1 will be deleted, row 2 and 3 tetangga1's value will be updated to null

how can i achieve it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want either a `delete` trigger or a cascading foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a foreign key relationship defined appropriately:

```
alter table t
    add constraint fk_t_tetangga1
        foreign key (tetangga1) references t(id)
        on delete set NULL;
```

This is actually better than a trigger.  The database will maintain the relational integrity.

Comment: if i were to add foreign key constraint, should i make a duplicate of that table or not?

Comment: from what i read on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint

on delete cannot be set null if the referenced key is primary key since primary key cannot be set to null