# General error: 1215 in laravel migration php

Tags: php, laravel

this is my error:

```
General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `author_book` add constraint `author_book_author_id_foreign` foreign key (`author_id`) references `author` (`id`))
```

I have table books and author with pivot table:

```
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->unsignedInteger('pages');
        $table->string('ISBN');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->date('published_at');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

author table:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('author');
        $table->date('birthdate');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and my pivot table:

```
            $table->increments('id');

        $table->unsignedInteger('author_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('book_id');

        $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('author');
        $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('books');
        $table->timestamps();
```

help me please to find error!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the author**s** table. Forgot the `s`.

```
$table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors');
//                                                        ^
```