# How to add foreign key after creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Since this is my first day of learning SQL, I am trying to add a foreign key to a column in a table referring to another column in another table. I am getting an error like "Error Code 1215: Cannot add Foreign Key Constraint". I have read the documentation on many websites, I couldn't get any solutions. I am not familiar with technical language or knowledge in SQL, so help me with simple answers to proceed further. Thanks in advance.

Here is the snippet I used to add a foreign key to an existing table.
"ALTER TABLE location_details ADD CONSTRAINT FK_location FOREIGN KEY (Zip) REFERENCES student_details(Zip);"

Comment: Do you have existing data that conflicts with this foreign key? Like a row in `location_details` with a `Zip` that doesn't exist in any row in `student_details`?

Comment: What is the DDL of your tables? You can add FK only to unique columns (unique or PK constrained)

Comment: i have **Zip** as a column in both the **location_details** and **student_details**, but  **Zip** in **students_details** table is not Unique.

Comment: @astentx I have added DDL in the question.

Comment: *I have added DDL in the question.* Where? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncuId.png - I do not see..

Comment: I hope this is the DDL, "ALTER TABLE location_details ADD CONSTRAINT FK_location FOREIGN KEY (Zip) REFERENCES student_details(Zip);" Correct me if i m wrong.

Comment: DDL of the tables. But I'm sorry for wrong statement, My SQL allows you to build weird model with non-unique referenced column: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74181e98c25107ca4b036a42a809c83d)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: Solved the issue. Also pls clarify that,                                                                            "ALTER TABLE location_details ADD CONSTRAINT FK_location FOREIGN KEY (Zip) REFERENCES student_details(Zip);" is this said to be DDL of the table?

Comment: What do we do if a Foreign Key from child table referrring to Primary Key in Parent Table(if more than one column is said to be primary key)?