# Cannot add a foreign key constraint MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a table named **"countries"** and another table named **"country_continents"** in my DB. I want to make my `continent_id` column in **countries** , a *foreign key* referencing the *id of **country_continents***, but I am getting an error message. This is the SQL to create the foreign key and the error:

```
ALTER TABLE countries
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_continent_id
    FOREIGN KEY (continent_id)
    REFERENCES country_continents(id);
```

> ERROR:
> #1215 - cannot add foreign key constraint

At first, I was getting the :

> "Error: relational features are disabled"

so I ran the command `ALTER TABLE countries ENGINE=InnoDB;` and `ALTER TABLE country_continents ENGINE=InnoDB;` but now I'm getting the **#1215 error.**

This is the Structure for **"country_continents"**:
[image]

This is the Structure for **"countries"**:
[image]

Any ideas on whats happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `country_continents(id)` declared as the primary key?

Comment: Are they the same data type ? Please share tables definitions. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, it is the primary key.

Comment: @Akina the tables were created from migration in Laravel, so I do not have the CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` and provide the output.

Comment: Does some data is present in the tables already?

Comment: Please publish the code for creating your tables `countries` and `country_continents`

Comment: Just fixed the issue, thank you so much for all the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is due to:

in your **countries** table, `continent_id` is not **unsigned**.
Edit that and tell me if it worked